# React Router - How to Determine If Back button was hit?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these scenarios

Settings Page -> Results Page -> Details Page

User chooses settings, clicks next, gets results and then clicks into more details.

Details Page -> Results Page

User goes back to Results page from Details Page. This causes a full re-render, causing me to hit the server again for no point(I have the results stored in an array).

Details Page -> Results Page -> Settings Page -> Results Page

The user goes to details, then back to results(want to grab stored results), then goes back to settings page, makes changes and then goes back to results page(now I want a full grab from server again).

I am wondering if there is away in react router to determine if I came to the page via the browser history or if I was going in a forward motion.

Comment: Is Details route a child of Results route? I have a scenario in my application where this is the case and Details being child of Results doesn't re-render Results (I have a master-detail view type of a setup and there are no requests going to Results). Also, are you fetching data in `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: No it is it's on route. I have done any children routes before, maybe will look into that(is it called child routes). I have the ajax call in componentDidMount

Comment: Are you using `Link` component to change from one view to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Router, the component stays mounted if router calls for paths that are children of that component. So, in your example, you can do something like the following:

```
<Route path="items" component={Results}>
    <Route path=":id" component={Detail} />
</Route>
```

This way, `Results` component does not get unmounted when `Detail` component is being mounted because `Detail` is a child of `Results`. However, if you do not want to see Results component getting rendered when you are in Detail, you can only render children when they exist. Something like the following:

```
 class Results extends React.Component {

     render() {
         if (this.props.children) {
             // This will enter Detail component
             return this.props.children;
         }
         return (
             // Render results component
         );
     }
 }
```

Comment: what do I put for the "to" in <Link to=? />

Comment: In my experience `to` always worked relative to "/". So, I would just write `to={'/items/' + id}`

Comment: hmm have not been able to get it working yet. Did what you have, my ulrl changes to /#/results/0 but thats it page does not change.

Comment: Can you test it with `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory` in the router?

Comment: No change, only other thing I can think maybe that is effecting it is the <Link> in another component called Result. so it actually is Results ->  Result -> Detail though Result is dumb component and renders each individual result and is a child or Results which is the container.

Comment: Do you have any error or warning in console router?

Comment: Console router? I don't have any in chrome developer tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134034/discussion-between-gasim-and-chobo2).

Comment: I had a chance to try what we chated about yesterday. It does work, if you want to post the full answer up I will accept it as the "accepted answer"

Answer (score 9):

I was looking for the same thing then I finally find a solution that seems simple.

**Quick answer:**

I use `history.action` value to determine if the user is coming from a back button or from a classic navigation.
If `history.action` is equal to `'POP'` then the back button has been hit. Otherwise it's `'PUSH'`.

**Detailed answer:**

I get access to history in props of each page because I do something like that:

```
<Provider store = { store }>
    <AppRouter />
</Provider>
```

Where `AppRouter` is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';
import PageHome from '../pages/front/home/PageHome';

export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router history={ history }>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <PublicRoute
                    exact = { true }
                    path = "/"
                    component = { PageHome }
                    history={ history }
                />
                < ..... Other routes here ..... >
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

And `PublicRoute` component is something like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/header/Header';

const PublicRoute = ( { component: Component, ...rest } ) => (
    <Route
        component={ ( props ) => (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Component { ...props } />
            </div>
        )}
        { ...rest }
    />
);

export default PublicRoute;
```

Comment: Is there any way I could know the page from which the back button was pressed ?..i mean the route.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are mostly old.
You can use useBlocker() from react-router-dom which will help you in detecting scenarios when you navigate to other page.

Example code for usage:

```js
import {
  useBlocker
} from "react-router-dom";

let blocker = useBlocker(
  ({
    currentLocation,
    nextLocation
  }) =>
  currentLocation.pathname !== nextLocation.pathname && unsavedChanges
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (blocker.state === "blocked") {
    setOpenSaveContentModal(true);
  }
}, [blocker]);
```