# React Router v4 - How to detect back button navigation vs url refresh?

Tags: react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4, history.js

I have a url at `/page` **(PAGE A)** where I want to detect if the page was navigated to with history back from **(PAGE B)** or if the user was on **(PAGE A)** and manually refreshed the page from the URL bar refresh button (without using history back).

I looked into all the history, location, props by react router but didn't find a way to differentiate how the user navigated to the page.

In both scenarios, the `history.action == 'POP'` is the history action. Ideally it would be `'POP'` when using the back button in the app to go back from page b to page a, and when on page a, when refreshing the page, it would be something other than `'POP'` like `'REFRESH'` for example.

How can we differentiate between both of them to run different logic in our app, since both trigger `'POP'`?

Comment: use history, add listener and listen for pop, https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Comment: I think you are looking for this kind of thing I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41862910/react-router-how-to-determine-if-back-button-was-hit/51745249#51745249

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing the history key, you can compare the pathname, for example, if you are in the page "/page1/page2" and hit refresh, the new location is the same. But if you hit the back action, the new location will be "/page1/".

This solution also uses a listener to listen to any action coming from history.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
        if (action == 'POP') {
          \\ thisLocation is the current location of your page
          if (location.pathname != '/thisLocation/') {
            alert('Back Pressed: ' + String(location.pathname));
          } else {
            alert('Refreshed: ' + String(location.pathname));
          }
        }
    });
    this.setState({ ...this.state, unlisten: unlisten });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.unlisten();
  }
```

You can see more details in the link provided by Rei Dien as a comment of your question: https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

[EDIT]

Another way to do this is using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-last-location and doing this:

```
import { useLastLocation } from 'react-router-last-location';

  componentDidMount() {
    const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
          const lastLocation = useLastLocation();
          if (location.pathname == lastLocation.pathname) {
            alert('Back Pressed: ' + String(location.pathname));
          }
        }
    });
    this.setState({ ...this.state, unlisten: unlisten });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.unlisten();
  }
```

The downside is that there is no difference between activating the back action or clicking in a link that goes to the page that you was before, both would be detected as pressing back. If you don't want a new dependency, you can do it manually as stated in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1066#issuecomment-412907443 creating a middleware.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately that did not work either. Even going back triggers Refreshed and a page refresh does not trigger any alert. I am surprised a solution to this isn't built into the react router library!

Comment: That's curious. It worked perfectly well here. Try to put an alert on the else of the if (action == 'POP') with the action as argument. I will update the answer with another solution if you are always receiving PUSH actions. If that's the case, you will need to make a middleware to be able to store the last location and compare to the next one.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the effort on your answer. I awarded you to bounty since it was about to expire and I wanted you to have it instead of it being lost. I still didn't find a way to solve it but posted on the react/history repo on github. If I get something working I will post here as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, I am still willing to find a solution to your problem. Seems like there is no built-in way to differenciate these actions tho https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/575. The best I can see for now is something like I said to considerate a refresh as 'no location change' and a back action as 'location changed'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will at least point your in the right direction. Navigate to yourwebsite.com.

```
let current_page = history.state.key

if(history.action == 'POP') {
  if(history.state.key == current_page) {
    return 'page was refreshed'
  }
  return 'back button was pressed'
}
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried that but there is no key on state, only on location. I changed `history.location.key` instead of `history.state.key` but that returns 'page was refreshed' regardless of a page refresh or going back to the page. The keys are exactly the same, so we still can't differentiate a refresh from going back to the page.